# how json parameter pass in asp.net web api action method

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My asp.net web api is an standalone application,face problem to pass json sa a parameter.My api method is bellow

```
[Route("api/UniqueUser/{userInfo}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetUniqueUserByEmail(string userInfo)
{
}
```

In above parameter **userInfo** is a josn like bellow

```
{"UserInfo":[{"Id":1,"UserName":"Jxj Bdn","Email":"a@a.com"}]}
```

When I put this in my browser url show me bellow error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JSON data should go in the body of the request for it to be deserialized, not in the query string/browser URL.

Also, 'string userInfo' will not work as you expect. You can define a class that represents the parameters of your JSON object and it will work correctly.

This would work, for example:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string UserName  { get; set;}

    public string Email  { get; set;}
}
```

and change this line:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUniqueUserByEmail(UserInfo userInfo)
```

Edit:

If it's a url that someone needs to pass in you use routing:

```
https://site/api/UniqueUser/1/Jxj Bdn/a@a.com
```

And in your controller:

```
[Route("api/UniqueUser/{id}/{userName}/{email}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUniqueUserByEmail(int id, string userName, string email)
```

Have a look here to see how to do this with traditional query string parameters too:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

I would strongly suggest using the first method though, it gives you a strongly type object and is a lot easier to deal with if details change, and you get the benefit of the build in model validation.

Can you not make a simple HTML form for your clients to use?

Comment: as i say it's a service application,so i need to give user just a url nothing else,in this situation what i do.